# Showing that the directional derivative is equal to $\dot{g}(0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have the following question:

> Let $\mathbb{R}_u^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Show that if $c:(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \mathbb{R}_u^n$ is any smooth curve with $c(0) = u, \dot{c}(0) = v,$ then $D_vf = \dot{g}(0)$ where $g=fc$.

I also have the answer which I am unable to understand:

> Noting that $\dot{g}(0) = dg_0(1)$ we have,
> $$
>     \dot{g}(0) = dg_0(1) = df_{c(0)} dc_0 (1) = df_u (\dot{c}(0)) = df_u(v) = D_vf.
> $$

I am unable to convince myself why $\dot{g}(0) = dg_0(1)$ which is an identity that is also used in the third equality; mainly because I don't know where the $1$ is coming from, since all the data concerns itself with evaluating everything at $0$. Any illumination would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$ you have that $dg_x(t)=g'(x) \cdot t$ for definition of derivative (and on the other hand for definition of differential). Thus $dg_0(1)=g'(0) \cdot 1=g'(0)$